# How to reconfigure Raspbian such that it can detect the wifi (WLAN) signal?

Tags: wifi

I want to use the Raspberry Pi to access the WLAN. I have two SD cards, each one has a different version of the Raspbian Buster operating system. With one of the operating systems, I have no problem detecting and connecting to the WLAN. With the other operating system, I can't even detect the signal of the sought after WLAN, although it does detect several other WLAN signals from the neighborhood.

With the machine that gets no access to the WLAN:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.11-v7+
```

With the machine that gets access to the WLAN:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.75-v7+
```

Please somebody help me be telling me how to reconfigure this machine, such that it can connect to WLAN.

Comment: Have you configured the WLAN Country using raspi-config? it's under "Localisation Options"

Comment: The one that doesn't get access to the WLAN in question has the WLAN Country setting DE, because I am in Germany. But I don't think that is the issue, because:
(1) I do manage to use this system to access other WLANs.
(2) With this system I can detect several other WLANs in the neighborhood, whereas with this system I can't even detect the WLAN to which I want to connect.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't understand that part of the question, you can see all WLAN's except the one you want to connect to!

Comment: That's right. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: I take it you don't have a hidden SSID?

Comment: I am not sure. How would I know if it is a hidden SSID? I rather assume it is not hidden SSID, because my other devices--including an Android phone and an X86 Linux computer--all detect it.